How to set up signed git commits in PyCharm for a WSL2 project
When I commit through the IDE, I get this error:
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 27802 gnome3:curses 1.1.1 - xterm-256color :0.0 - 1000/1000 -
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 83918950
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fatal: failed to write commit object

I have gotten around this by modifying my .bashrc when I run on the command line, but PyCharm doesn't seem to inherit from that.
